# Compare String in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to check whether string is empty or not

when i create `object=Shared.getLocal("abc");`

it assigns undefinded to the object at the first time

```
 if(object.data.name=="undefnied") {
         // is this correct   
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [hasOwnProperty](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29) function to test if the variable exists. For example:

```
    if ( object.data.hasOwnProperty("name") ){
        // Ok. object.data.name exists...
        var value_of_name : String = String(object.data["name"]);

        // Check for non-null, non-empty
        if ( value_of_name ){
             // Ok. It is a non-null, non-empty string
             // ...
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

undefined is a value, not a string to compare to. You want:

```
if (object.data.name == undefined) {
    //This property on your SharedObject was/is not defined.
}
```

Note that setting a property on a SharedObject to null does not delete it, it must be deleted with "delete".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with flex, but it should be `undefined` or `null` without quotes, I think.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question (if is empty), I'd do this:

```
var name : String = object.data.name;
if(name != null && name.length > 0) {
    //also, a common actionScript technique is to say if(name && name.length...)
    //same difference.
}
```